# is it possible to attach HTML through JS on a page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reference

im curious to know if it's possible to remotely upload or reference a .html document from a file server through the javascript **onload** function. I have found out how to implement CSS & JS through the onload function but not quite the HTML. . i would be using this for a CMS that i use daily that limits my page customization..

Implementing JS example:

```
<img style="display: none;" src="IMAGE_NEEDED_FOR_ONLOAD_IMPLEMENTATION" onload="var body=document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]; var script=document.createElement('script'); script.type='text/javascript'; script.src='JAVASCRIPT_FILE_GOES_HERE'; body.appendChild(script);">
```

Anybody happen to have a clue or have experience with this?
I'm not looking to use an iFrame. 
Also, would this harm SEO?

Comment: You want to "remotely upload or reference a .html document from a file server through the javascript onload function"? Could you reword this so it's easier to understand what do you want to achieve?

Comment: i edited the original post. please see above :)

Comment: You can use AJAX to get another HTML document, then assign to `element.innerHTML` to update the current page with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you want to do is to make an AJAX call to that HTML file. Please read [Getting started with AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started).

What you would need to do next is to add the result to your page, not with `body.appendChild(script);` this time but with the process described in this [AJAX HTML injection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36432366/2619362) answer.

EDIT:
As for SEO, this used to be a clear "yes, it's problematic" as search engine crawlers did not have Javascript enabled but then last year Google started enabling JS in its crawlers, which is a good thing but also made the issue muddier. [This article](http://searchengineland.com/can-now-trust-google-crawl-ajax-sites-235267) may be outdated but it runs through some of the uncertainties. I would say if you even think this could be an issue, you should probably look deeper into [progressive enhancement](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/04/progressive-enhancement-what-it-is-and-how-to-use-it/). Or you can go ahead, implement in the client, measure the SEO impact after a while and assess whether it's worth changing the implementation too.

Comment: do you know if ajax requests have any SEO value?