# How to get a JavaScript information printed in an html tag on another page via ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to get a processed information in a JavaScript function from another html page. But I can only get the source code.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://example.com/',
    async: false,
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data) {
        $('#testandodaiane').html($(data).find('#permissao').html());
        console.log('data',data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Read this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36432366/2813224) and if it helps upvote.

Comment: @zer00ne, rather mercenary of you, no? Shouldn't you just close this as a duplicate?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I hate the duplicate process, but by all means you may go through the process, sir.

Comment: @DaianeRangel, Perhaps you can provide more information about what that other page has? For instance, what does the element with the id "permissao" contain? If it's script, then getting the `html()` from it is not going to be of any benefit. Do also note that using `async: false` has been deprecated for quite a while.

Comment: @zer00ne I tested the solution indicated and it did not work for me.
The result was the same as I had with my code. I received the source code for the page. And not the information processed.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan The "permission" element contains a javascript function that tells whether a user is allowed to receive push notification in domain A. And I want to have access to that information in domain B.

Comment: If it's JavaScript, just move it to a file of its own, and include it in both pages, or use `$.getScript()`....

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan It is not a script, it is a Notification object available in the browser of the other domain. In this case it is Notification.permission.

Comment: Yeah, so, when you ask a question, it's really a good idea to give as much information as possible in the question... see [ask]. For instance, an example of what exactly is in the this file that you're pulling. I should note that a "Notification object" must be implemented in JavaScript or HTML's `object` element, so it's one or the other...

Answer (score 1):

You can't call a javascript function in a different web page, or extract markup from a different web page.  You CAN include the javascript files that the other page uses.

Seems like you're trying to build a *web service*.  Client-side javascript is not the tool.